# Writing a patch on a sandbox/dev install using a git branch

Tags: version-control

I'm working with a Sandbox/Dev hosted VM with Drupal 7 and Commons 3. I want to write and perhaps contribute a patch. Having the site under local version control with git, I create a new branch write and test the code.

However, I'm at a loss how to create the patch file between the two branches (master and writing-patch).

Do I switch back the master? How do I compare two branches and properly put that into a patch file with the intention of sharing with a module maintainer? I'd like to do this properly and put as little work on the maintainer as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the module you want to patch and do a:

```
git diff original_branch final_branch > /path/to/file.patch
```

Test it by applying the patch to the initial module:

```
patch -p1 < /path/to/file.patch
```

or

```
git apply --index /path/to/file.patch
```

More info:

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_patch.htm

https://drupal.org/node/707484